# Laravel Eloquent Not Created_At today

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Alright so I'm trying to make a query in which the users who were not `created_at` this day are selected and I'm having a little trouble. Everything I've tried they're still selected. Here is some of the stuff I've tried (with no success):

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->get()
$users = User::where('created_at', '!=', new DateTime())->get()
$users = User::where('created_at', '!=', date('Y-m-d'))->get()
$users = User::where('created_at', '!=', new DateTime('today'))->get()
```

I also tried using the `<>` operator instead of `!=`.

I suspect that the issue lies in the fact that the users were not created 'this second', so it has them as not equal and they pass through. How can I fix this?

Side note: I'm using SQLite for development but will be using Postgres on the live site so I would like something compatible with both.

Comment: may be you could have used whereDate() function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

use \Carbon\Carbon;

...

$start = (new Carbon('now'))->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
$end = (new Carbon('now'))->hour(23)->minute(59)->second(59);

$trans = User::whereNotBetween('created_at', [$start , $end])->get();
```

Comment: Does it work for code outside Laravel? I mean I only use Eloquent without Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, if you are using composer, just `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` and it should work.

Comment: You could also go a shorter way: 
$start = Carbon::today()->startOfDay();
$end = Carbon::today()->endOfDay()

$trans = User::whereNotBetween('created_at', [$start , $end])->get();